# How to write the SQL ORDER BY {value} DESC LIMIT statement in LINQ to Entities (Entity Framewok)?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'd trying to write the following SQL query in LINQ to Entities, how can I do that?

```
SELECT codigo FROM Vendas ORDER BY codigo DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I know how to use the `DESC`, but what about the `LIMIT 1`. I could write this peace of code with the thing I know, but it will obviously throw an exception if there is more than one row on table `Vendas`:

```
using (TccContext db = new TccContext())
{
    var query = (from venda in db.Vendas
                 orderby venda.codigo descending // `LIMIT 1` in LINQ should be added here I think
                 select venda).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using (TccContext db = new TccContext())
{
    var query = (from venda in db.Vendas
                 orderby venda.codigo descending
                 select venda).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If you need Enumerable with one element (actually analog of SQL `limit`):

```
using (TccContext db = new TccContext())
{
    var query = (from venda in db.Vendas
                 orderby venda.codigo descending
                 select venda).Take(1);
}
```

Comment: @Zignd Notice, that both queries provide different results. First of type `venda`, second - IEnumerable of type `venda`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan yeah I saw that when tested the both solutions, so I decided to use the first so I don't need to convert it from a collection with only one row into a single row.